# Azure Queue Storage: Value cannot be null, how to fix Azure Queue Storage error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I am getting this error when running my Azure function locally on my machine.
The function is running fine on my colleagues machine but I am getting the below error:

[2023-08-22T07:44:21.803Z] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[2023-08-22T07:44:21.805Z] Azure.Storage.Queues: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value').

[image]

Could you please help me out on how to fix this issue?
The function is running perfectly on Cloud as well.

I tried restarting my machine and visual studio but still the error persists.

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Do you add the connection string in the **local.setting.json**? Can you check it once if not yet added, try to add it and try to run it again.

Comment: I have the connection string already in the settings

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file and `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: What is the version of your Azure Function?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Queue Storage: Value cannot be null.

This is generic error which occurs if there is any misconfiguration.

- Check if the connection string you are passing is valid and correct.

**Connection String format:**

```
connection=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage_account>;AccountKey=p+9xt+XXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

- If you are passing any values, make sure its case-insensitive.
- Make sure you have configured everything required in your Azure function properly.

---

I have tried to reproduce the issue with a basic Blob trigger Azure function, and it worked without any issues:

**Code:**

```cs
 public class Function1
 {
     [FunctionName("Function1")]
     public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "demo")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
     {
         log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
     }
 }
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "demo": <Storage_connection_string>
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]